# hide real Id on entity from end user

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm building e-commerce application. Path to the order looks like `/Orders/Details/{orderId}`.
However I don't want expose orderId to the end-user. 
How can I identify order, not using database identifier?
Is it necessary to generate some random unique string like GUID?

Comment: I think it would help to understand your motivations behind wanting to do this?

Comment: user makes an order, he sees it id - 1000 for example, next day he makes another order and new order's id is 1050 - now user knows that I have 50 orders for one day- I don't want him to know that.

Comment: Then I would go with the first option in my answer, and adding an alternate key. This could be a hash of the actual order ID, or just a random number that you generate. Anything you like that is unique and you are happy to show customers.

Comment: I agree, using hash of unique id makes sense, but in your previous comment you said, it's not safe to use hashes)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I meant a cryptographic hash, rather that the hashcode generated for objects by whatever language you are using. For example, an SHA1 hash is a 160-bit hash - so there is virtually no chance of collisions. It is also going to be the same across application executions for any given value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to assign some other identifier to the entity that you didn't mind users seeing (some kind of alternate key).

Alternatively you could use encrypted or obfuscated IDs, and have your application handle decryption or de-obfuscation.

Comment: if userId and orderDate uniquely identifies order, would it be safe to use (userId.asString() + orderDate.asString()).hashCode()?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track - using a integer as the orderid can lead to forceful browsing attack. May be you can use a GUID as the primary key in your database.

Comment: it can be a problem to use GUID in url

Comment: It's important to note that you should not rely *solely* on such 'obfuscation'; you should still ensure that unauthorised users cannot do anything nefarious just by knowing the ID of an entity.

Answer (score 0):

You could post a value to the order/details page, and send the orderID that way. You could also possibly have some other unique string for orders and use that instead, depending on how you are storing the data and why you want to hide the orderID.